# how to solve application disappearing after console readline a negative number?

Tags: c#

So I wrote a short code in c#, and it's function is like this:

First you choose how many times you want to put in a number, then you pick a number to sum

```
static void number()
{
    Console.WriteLine("how many numbers, max is 999");
    int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (n > 999)
    {
        return;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("enter number here:");
    int d = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (d < -99999 || d > 99999)
    {
        return;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(n + " " + d + "which number has to be counted up");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int e = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int c;
        c = e + d;
        Console.WriteLine(e + " " + c);
        Console.WriteLine("press enter to input a new number");
        Console.ReadKey();
        i++;
    }
}
```

If I put positive numbers, it works correctly. But if I put in negative numbers, It asks "enter number here" and after I put in a number, it shows the which number to count up writeline very quickly and then the application stops for no reason.

Any thoughts why this happens?

Comment: Looks like you're incrementing `i` twice in your `for` loop..

Comment: Have you [asked a rubber duck](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)? Have you stepped through the program using the debugger?

Comment: @Phateriver, you need to review your own code as well as understand what it is you're writing.. if you are doing a for loop and the last arg in the for loop is the incrementer, then why do you need `i++` at the end of your for loop.. this is basic coding

Answer (score 1):

If you put a negative number into `n`, then `i` will never be less than `n` in your for loop (which you've set to run while `i < n`). This means the the for loop will never run and the as this is the last bit of code in you application, the program will end.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I get:

```
how many numbers, max is 999
-2
enter number here:
3
-2 3which number has to be counted up
```

When I enter the `-2` it gets stored in the variable `n`. Later, in the for loop, the variable `i` starts out at zero, which means the `i < n`, so the loop quits without executing anything in the loop body.